# How to install CVS in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, cvs

I am trying to install cvs in eclipse but it is showing the below error. I have also tried other step like click on install new software-> select eclipse->search cvs. But still I am not able to install

[click_here_to_see_error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mum5R.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Does in the preferences _Install/Update > Available Software Sites_ adding the update site [`https://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.22`](https://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.22) before installing _CVS Version Tree_ via the Marketplace work?

Comment: @StephenC The CVS support feature has been removed and is no longer provided by the current update sites. But I guess, installing it from an older update site into the current Eclipse will still work.

Comment: ... as you said on the Q&A I just linked to.

Comment: @StephenC Yes, but here something cannot be installed via the Eclipse Marketplace that requires CVS support. Instead of just using a different update site URL (which is not possible in the Marketplace), the older update site for CVS support must be added to the preferences here. I am fine with closing this as a duplicate. With my comment I just wanted to provide more specific guidance here.

Comment: Thanks!. It worked on after adding cvs from https://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.22